# Why central bright spot (in youngs double slit experiment ) is not considered as the first bright spot , although the central is brightest one?

Tags: optics, waves

I have read that in youngs double slit experiment , the bright spot appears whenever there is a constructive interference (nlambda*D/d) .
But i want to know why the first bright spot is taken at n=1 ? why not at the central ?(n=0).

Comment: for symmetry? if you labeled the central as one , then on its left the next would be 2 but on its right 1, inconsistent with the symmetry observed. Having a zero at the center counts the peaks symmetrically as observed to be around the peak.

Comment: relevant  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/443892/in-youngs-double-slit-experiment-can-there-be-an-even-number-of-maxima-in-the